# Polynomial multiplication in finite field without smooth-order roots of unity

Tags: runtime-analysis, polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

I am working in a finite prime field $\mathbb{F}_p$ that does not have primitive $n$-th roots of unity for any large smooth integer $n$, which makes FFTs a bit difficult.

If I need to compute a product of linear polynomials $\prod\limits_{i=0}^n (X+a_i)$, can I do so in runtime $O(n\cdot \log^2(n))$?

How bad is the slowdown if I try to use FFTs in a field without all the n-th roots of unity? Do I need to pass to the smallest field extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ that does contain a primitive $n$-th root in order to compute the product in sub-quadratic runtime?

Comment: You mentioned field extensions...  This is just a shot in the dark, but if you can adjoin values to $\mathbb{F}_p$ to get $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, you can use the Frobenius transform which runs in $(n \log{n}) / k$, even faster than the FFT.